# Rails has_many through with simple_form devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Okay so I have a user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :positions, :through => :user_positions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions
end
```

This User can has_many positions:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :users, :through => :user_positions
end
```

Through user_positions:

```
class UserPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :position
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :position
end
```

I have a form to display all these positions as checkboxes:

```
  <%= simple_form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
      <%= f.association :positions, as: :check_boxes %>
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "button" %>
      <%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
        or
        <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name), class: "button" %>
      <% end -%>
  <% end %>
```

and I am using devise to process the registration with only the following override:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, :only => [:create]

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :position_ids) }
  end

end
```

I built this by cherry-picking many answers off of this site....yet for some reason it STILL doesn't save the positions. I'm not sure what else im supposed to be doing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `position_ids` would be passed as an array, you need to update `configure_permitted_parameters` as below:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :position_ids => []) }
  end
```

Comment: ah yes i remember that now....gah, going to have to go back and watch those codeschool videos all over again. Been too long. I'll try this out and if it works mark the answer appropriately

Comment: Yeah that still had no effect. Created a user just fine....no issues...but no positions attached